# Syntax Code Operator

Tags: programming-languages

Anyone who can explain or read this syntax?

```
int deltax := x1 - x0
```

Like what does ":" do? Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged with three different languages?

Comment: It seems to illegal in none of the languages you tagged.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta means you should explain this in all those languages :D

Comment: Excellent question. Luckily the answer is the same in all three

Comment: `:=` is assignment in a number of languages. Pascal in particular.

Comment: or delphi, or postgresql

Comment: because its just a pseudo code and related to those tags.

Comment: See section Parallel assignment & Notation on [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_programming%29)

Answer (score 3):

It does nothing in C or Java. In all likelihood, the person who wrote that is used to programming languages where `=` is a comparison and `:=` is an assignment. However, in C and Java, `==` is the comparison and `=` is the assignment. It's clear that they meant:

```
int deltax = x1 - x0
```

Comment: Does nothing is different from being incorrect, also assignment and initialization are different.

Answer (score 2):

`:=` was the usual assignment operator in languages such as [ALGOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL), [Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29), [Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29), etc. You frequently see `:=` used in [hand-written pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) as an easy way to tell assignment from equality testing. (In hand-written contexts, `=` often means equality rather than assignment.)

As an aside, in Erlang, the `=` symbol is used for [pattern matching](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id75584): using `=` in function definitions or case statements allow for selecting a code branch based on which expressions or guards *match* the input. `=` can also serve as an `assert` would in other languages if used in a "procedural" context -- if the left side does not match the right side, execution stops.

Comment: In Pascal I was taught to read the `:=` syntax as "set equal to".

Comment: I've also heard it pronounced "set", "assigns", "let", and plain old "equals" -- we're so used to "equals" meaning "assign" these days... :)